# Yum update - /bin/python not found

Tags: redhat, python, yum

I'm trying to update a Red Hat 7 system but cannot due to the following dependency message:

```
Error: Package: Trac-1.0.12-1.noarch (@/Trac-1.0.12-1.noarch)
           Requires: /bin/python
           Removing: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
               Not found
           Updated By: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               Not found
```

/bin/python certainly does exist. I get the following from 'whereis python':

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

As you can see, no /bin/python - is this significant? I'm not sure where whereis gets its info from.

'which python' returns /bin/python.

I need this system to update cleanly - any suggestions will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to check is that your repositories are still enabled:

```
yum repolist all
```

This should return your repositories and the status of them.
Check if you have rhel-7-server repo id and see if the status is still enabled.

If disabled use your subscription manager to enable the repository:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server
```

If that doesn't work please check your subscription:

```
subscription-manager version
```

If there is a line "registered to: Unknown" then you should update your subscription.

Comment: All repos look fine using those checks. Yum clean all and yum update don't help either. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it organized in RHEL, but in CentOS `/bin/python` is symlink to `python2`, which is symlink to `python2.7`. So you could create a `/bin/python` as symlink to any `python2.7` presented in your system.

Answer (score 0):

This was yum being dumb (or me?). I simply did 'yum update python', let that run then did 'yum update'. All issues resolved...